# Parallel insert into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

What happens, if two clients, working with one MongoDB instance, perform and insert operation at same time without «forceServerObjectId: true». Is it possible to be generated equal ObjectIDs, is there may be a conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implied unique index on the _id field of every collection which makes it impossible for two objects with the same _id to exist in the same collection.

When two objects with the same _id value are stored with `collection.save`, one document will replace the other.

When they are stored with `collection.insert`, one of the inserts will fail with a duplicate key error.

But note that [MongoDB ObjectIDs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) include a 24bit machine-ID. This makes it impossible for two clients to generate the same ID, unless they have the same machine-ID. And even then it's unlikely. That, of course, only applies when you let the MongoDB driver (or shell) auto-generate ObjectIDs. MongoDB allows to use any value of any type as a value for the _id field when you set it manually. When you do this (you shouldn't), it's your responsibility to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I am facing this issue as i am doing parallel insertion on the same machine..so may i know what can be done..? as waiting for completing 1 and then proceeding to next will create performance issue. Thanks in advance!